# Polymer import dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm working with a Product Listing Mobile App using `Polymer`

So i wanted to load the product details like 3 images decription and other details when click on the thumbnail,

I'm using `core-animated-pages` to show the product thumbnail and Detail view

**Here is the HTML**

```html
<div id="article-content" >
<template is="auto-binding" id="page-template" >
 <core-ajax
    id="ajaxpolo" auto
    url="./json/products.json"
    handleAs="json"
    response="{{productList}}">
  </core-ajax>
<core-animated-pages id="fpages" flex selected="{{$.polo_cards.selected}}" on-core-animated-pages-transition-end="{{transitionend}}" transitions="cross-fade-all slide-from-right">
<section vertical layout>
      <div id="noscroll" fit hero-p>
        <div id="container" flex horizontal wrap around-justified layout cross-fade >
          <section on-tap="{{selectView}}" id="polo_cards" >

            <template repeat="{{item in productList}}">
              <div class="card" vertical center center-justified layout hero-id="item-{{item.id}}" hero?="{{$.polo_cards.selected === item.id || lastSelected === item.id }}" > <span cross-fade hero-transition style="">{{item.name}}</span></div>
            </template>
 </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <template repeat="{{item in productList}}">
      <section vertical layout>
        <div class="view" flex vertical center center-justified layout hero-id="item-{{item.id}}"    hero?="{{$.polo_cards.selected === item.id || $.polo_cards.selected === 0}}"   >
          <core-icon-button class="go_back" icon="{{$.polo_cards.selected != 0 ? 'arrow-back' : 'menu'}}" on-tap="{{goback}}"></core-icon-button>
          {{item.name}} <span cross-fade class="view-cont" style="height:1000px; overflow:scroll;"></span></div>
      </section>
    </template>


  </core-animated-pages>
</template>
```

```
 template.selectView = function(e,detail,sender){

    /* set core-animated page Selected */ 
   var i = e.target.templateInstance.model.item.id;
      sender.selected = i;


    });
```

if i Put all the details in Detail view it will take too long to load, so i wanted to load the HTML of each products when click on its thumbnail

how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use app-router to lazy-load the elements or html, especially with core-animated-pages. Works well with cordova as well to plug into the app. However, be cautious that since shadow DOM is not the default in Polymer 1.0 and `<core-animated-pages>` moved to `<neon-animated-pages>` with a significant difference in the apis, it no-longer works when you try to port to 1.0, at least not until it is re-worked. But, if you plan to stick to 0.5 or port to 1.0 without using core-animated-pages, it still works well. You can check it out [here](https://erikringsmuth.github.io/app-router/).

Comment: my products are dynamic, and i wanted to load the data from json, i'm not sure that how app-router can work in my case.

Comment: The links configured in `<app-router>` can be dynamic too. `<app-router>` takes path arguments from the url and passes to the custom element as attributes. Use that attribute with core-ajax to fetch json data and populate the loaded custom element. That is all you would need. Seriously, read `<app-router>` documentation.